# How to force conda to upgrade all packages, regardless of dependency graph?

Tags: conda

I usually end up with a bunch of out-of-date packages in my conda environment because some package I installed at one time has a pinned dependency (e.g. `scipy == 0.15.0`) and it prevents other packages (e.g. jupyter) from updating. How can I ignore the pins and force update all packages?

Comment: You may want to adjust the terms used in the question. Judging from your answer, you want to ignore previous **explicit specifications** (i.e., versions you had previously specified). That is not the same as ignoring the dependency graph, since you still want the packages you install to work together and include any dependencies they require.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
conda update --all --no-pin --no-channel-priority
```

This ignores all pinned packages, channel priority, and updates everything. Beware that this might break compatibility for some packages that really need a specific version of a package.

Comment: According to `conda update --help` it's `--no-pin` (not 'pins')?